# Repeating numbers random Android studio java random array problem

Tags: java, android, android-studio

i have a problen with random in arrays. It is like a quiz and i have arrays with questions,choises and answers. When i start my quiz , qustions are repeating
Know about shuffle but do not know how to use it 
i have a method:

```
 private void updateQuestion(int num){
    question.setText(mQuestionAvtor.getQuestion(num));
    answer1.setText(mQuestionAvtor.getChoice1(num));
    answer2.setText(mQuestionAvtor.getChoice2(num));
    answer3.setText(mQuestionAvtor.getChoice3(num));
    answer4.setText(mQuestionAvtor.getChoice4(num));
    mAnswear= mQuestionAvtor.getCorrectAnswear(num);
}
```

It updates my questions from another Class with arrays by a num.
This num i did by random :

```
updateQuestion(r.nextInt(mQuestionslength));
```

Example of updating questions

```
  answer1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.answear1);
    answer2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.answear2);
    answer3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.answear3);
    answer4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.answear4);
    question = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.question);


    n = r.nextInt(mQuestionslength);
    while (n == n_before)
        n = r.nextInt(mQuestionslength);
    n_before = n;
    updateQuestion(n);
    answer1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if(answer1.getText()==mAnswear){
                mScore++;
                mScorecurrent.setText("Рахунок: "+mScore);
            }

            n = r.nextInt(mQuestionslength);
            while (n == n_before) n = r.nextInt(mQuestionslength);
            n_before = n;
            updateQuestion(n);
        }
    });
```

I need to do it in a such way , that r will not repeat. How can I do it?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you mean you want to prevent showing the same question again?

Comment: Yes! i have same questions repeating

Comment: As an aside, `answer1.getText()==mAnswear` will not work as this is a check for reference to a common object. For `String` comparison, use `mAnswear.equals(answer1.getText())`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First pre-create a random list of the questions you want to show.

```
Random rand = new Random();
List<Integer> rlist = new ArrayList<>();
while (rlist.size() != 4) {
int r = rand.nextInt(4) + 1;
if (!rlist.contains(r))
       rlist.add(r);
}
//output of rlist is like: [2, 3, 4, 1] or [1, 3, 4, 2]
```

Then count an index up after clicking the button and generate get a question with the current number.

```
int index = 0;
updateQuestion(rlist.get(index));
    answer1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (i < 4) {
            if(answer1.getText()==mAnswear){
                mScore++;
                mScorecurrent.setText("Рахунок: "+mScore);
            }


            updateQuestion(rlist.get(index));
            index++;
            } else {
                //To do after the last question
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Dont know why , just pasted this code but there are anyway repeating questions.

Comment: @Jugjin Try to put `int n = 0;
int n_before = 0;` in your class and not in any void or int. (Over your onCreate method)

Comment: Sorry for a stupid question. If i have have method updateQuestion(n) 4 times in my code - i should not write your code 4 times , just updateQuestion(n), right? Now questions are not repeating because they are not updating. When i choose correct answer - score is increasing but questions are not changed.

Comment: @Jugjin Let's try something. Replace your (4 times) `updateQuestion(n)` with `n = r.nextInt(mQuestionslength);
while (n == n_before)
n = r.nextInt(mQuestionslength);
n_before = n;
updateQuestion(n);`

Comment: Same. Questions are not changing.

Comment: @Jugjin When do you change the question? Does the user click a next button?

Comment: I have edited my post with an exapmle , when i use it.  At first i am just uptading them (without updating there will be empty buttons and empty textfields). Then game starts. And then updating after clicking on the answer ( no matter is it coorect or not answer)

Comment: @Jugjin Do you want to show a question just once in the full game or is it allowed to repeat a question?

Comment: I want to show my question only once in the full game.

Comment: Thank you, Jakob. Finally it works. But i changed a bit  { updateQuestion(rlist.get(index));
            index++;}   i firstly wrote index ++ ; and then updated question. Because we update them before start. And after first click. And we updated them ( before game starts and on a first click) with same index. That is why i had 2 similar questions at start. Nevertheless, now it works. Appreciate your help, Jakob!

Comment: Hope it's a last one. Why do we need "+1"in (int r = rand.nextInt(4) + 1) ? Sometimes i have ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException. ( I have checked it with your code, not edited mine)

Comment: @Jugjin Oh yes, it was my mistake. Remove  the +1 then we should get 0-3 wich is the range of your Array.

Comment: Sorry, Jakob. If i want to have array with size 15 and with index in range from 1 to 15. I should change in your code numbers to 16. But how to avoid **ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=15; index=15** if i have to add index++ ?

Comment: Created new question with additional info. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62243569/how-can-i-have-last-number-in-list-by-index-java-android-studio) **will be very grateful for any help**

Answer (score 1):

You can create an ArrayList of integers to store questions number already shown to the user and next time before setting question you can check if the questions number was already in ArrayList or not, If not ask the question to user.

```
    ArrayList<int> num  = ArrayList<int>()
    int temp = r.nextInt(mQuestionslength)
    while(num.contains(temp))
    {
        temp = r.nextInt(mQuestionslength)
    }
    num.add(temp);
    updateQuestion(temp);
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a famous algorithm called the Fisher-Yates Shuffle. [Here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/shuffle-a-given-array-using-fisher-yates-shuffle-algorithm/) is an implementation in Java. You can use it to shuffle the array of answers.